# Yii2.0/Rules for dropdownlist

Tags: yii

I've following dropdownlist:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Urlaubsziel')->dropdownList([
    1 => 'USA', 
    2 => 'Mexico',
    3 => 'Deutschland', 
    4 => 'England',
    5 => 'Frankreich',],['prompt'=>'Select Country']);?>
```

How to define a rule to get content of choice in public function rules(){}?
['Urlaubsziel','string'] just will give me the number,not the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like below.

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'Urlaubsziel')->dropdownList([
    'USA' => 'USA', 
    'Mexico' => 'Mexico',
    'Deutschland' => 'Deutschland', 
    'England' => 'England',
     'Frankreich' => 'Frankreich',],['prompt'=>'Select 
   Country']);?>
```